# Writing query with multiple varying conditions on data subset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query that searches through each MailID and selects ActivityId 1 that has an associated ActivityId 3 but not an associated ActivityId 7.

Here is a sample result set:

```
MailID | ActivityId
==============
155311406 | 1
154733588 | 3
154733588 | 1
154733588 | 7
154723283 | 1
154699790 | 1
154692365 | 7
154692365 | 1
154692365 | 3
154685546 | 7
154685546 | 1
154685546 | 3
154093013 | 1
153921107 | 3
153921107 | 7
153921107 | 1
153920994 | 3
153920994 | 1
153920932 | 7
153920932 | 3
153920932 | 1
```

I have attempted the query but I am not getting the correct output:

```
SELECT MailId, ActivityId
INTO #temp
FROM Mail WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE ActivityId IN (1, 3, 7)


SELECT MailID
FROM Mail M
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp T WHERE T.vNettId = M.vNettID AND T.ActivityId = 3)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp T WHERE T.vNettId = M.vNettID AND T.ActivityId = 7)
AND M.ActivityId = 1
```

Any help with this query would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
SELECT MailId
FROM Mail 
WHERE ActivityId IN (1, 3, 7)
GROUP BY MailId
HAVING MIN(ActivityId) = 1 AND
       MAX(ActivityId) = 3;
```

This is not super-generalizable.  A more general method is:

```
SELECT MailId
FROM Mail 
WHERE ActivityId IN (1, 3, 7)
GROUP BY MailId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ActivityId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN ActivityId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN ActivityId = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the query using `group by` and `having`.

```
SELECT MailId
FROM Mail 
WHERE ActivityId IN (1, 3, 7)
GROUP BY MailId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ActivityId IN (1,3) THEN ActivityId END)=2
AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ActivityId = 7 THEN ActivityId END)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any resultset from your query, because the field `vNettID` that seems to be used to associate MailIDs is not contained in your `#temp` table.

How about another query without a temporary table:

```
WITH T (vNettID) AS (
  SELECT vNettID
  FROM Mail
  WHERE ActivityID IN (3, 7)
  GROUP BY vNettID
  HAVING SUM(CASE ActivityID WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)
SELECT M.MailID
FROM Mail M 
  INNER JOIN T ON M.vNettID = T.vNettID
WHERE M.ActivityID = 1
```